# Is manualy updating JWT access_token data considered a bad practice?

Tags: python, security, flask, jwt

In my application I use custom data stored in token heavily - almost in every endpoint. Now I wanna add some data AFTER the user logs in (it's super important). I was wondering if kinda replacing old token with a new one is a bad practice?

Let's say user logs in and he receives this token:

```
{
...
"sub": {
    "someParam": false
},
...
}
```

but after some action I want `someParam` changed to `true`:

```
{
...
"sub": {
    "someParam": true
},
...
}
```

Comment: The user can still use the old token if they want to because the old token is still valid. Would that be a problem? Why do you want this in the first place?

Comment: I'll make old token revoked in redis - the user won't be able to use it again. There is an action which happens just after the user logs in and it affects every endpoint - having this information in the JWT token will decrease the changes I need to add to the codebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to use the JWT as a session storage mechanism, which is not a good practice. If you need to check the validity of the JWT in the database on every request why not just use sessions and keep the relevant data server side?

Also, how do you plan to deliver such an updated token to the user? I think that it will be much easier for you to keep the data in the backend and just use sessions.